# Windows Deployment Service - Multi OS answer file

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2012-r2, wds

I am very new to WDS and have a question for anyone experienced in it's use. This may not be achievable but from what I have read, there are indications that it can be, but I can't find any specific examples.

**Problem:** My employer has multiple answer files (Windows Server 2012, Windows Server 2008) and rather than have different answer files, it would be good to extract common configuration details into one answer file and have another inherit from it. I have read the concept of "passes" in what you can hook into the installation lifecycle, but the lifecycle itself cannot seem to be isolated into a separate XML file in which other answer files make use of it.

**Goal:** my goal is to have a PXE setup in which I select a "generic" image in the network installer settings and further down the line I select a specific installation (either Windows Server 2008 or Windows Server 2012).

**Question:** is the above achievable and if so can anyone point me at an example?

Given the lack of examples I can find, I suspect this isn't a desired approach to achieve what I want and the preferred approach is to have a one to one relationship between an image and an answer file.

Answer (score 1):

you already almost know the answer:

> the <s>preferred</s> approach is to have a one to one relationship between an
>   image and an answer file

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: It is indeed an answer that confirms one of the OP's guesses. It is not a critique nor it's needed any OP clarification either.

Comment: @pat, thanks. What makes me unsure is that an unattend file can be specified at the server level for each architecture type and an unattend file can be specified at the image level. So my thinking was that common stuff could be moved up to the generic unattend and image specific stuff could be left to the image unattend. So far, I've not had any success in doing this.